# DLL Functions and pointers

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I am absolutely new to DLLs, but not to C++. For a project I need to implement some functions in DLL. My question : can I pass pointers, from my main project, to functions inside DLLs without worrying about nothing ? I find it strange because the address in my main project are relatives, so the address passed to the DLL should mean something else. Is there a trick anywhere ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem. Both the EXE and the DLLs run in the same process so pointers point to the same place in memory both in the EXE and in the DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Any modules (exe, dll, etc.) in the same address space can be used the same pointer.

When OS execute the EXE. It will load the EXE to the virtual memory at the address specified in EXE header, or randomize address if EXE support relocation and ASLR (Address space layout randomization) is enabled. Then dependencies (All of DLL that EXE uses) will be loaded into the same address space afterward.

The things to be worried when you passed the pointer between modules is allocation and deallocation. You MUST use the same corresponding function to deallocate memory. If you use `HeapAlloc`, you must use `HeapFree` to free memory with the same heap.

In Visual C++, the real problems is `malloc` and `free` (`new` and `delete` too). Imagine module `A` allocate a block of memory with `malloc` and its compiled with Visual C++ 8.0. Module `B` compiled with Visual C++ 9.0. In this situation, you cannot use `free` in the module `B` to free a block of memory that allocated by `malloc` in the module `A`, since it is not the same corresponding functions.